# Temporary hinge bushing repair

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Trying to fix a Lenovo U510. I thought just the bottom case needed replacing, which it did, but when I opened it up I realized the reason the case was breaking was the brass bushings the hinge flange screws into had sheared off the top case. I'd like to get this working for my wife while I wait for the top case (the bushings are mounted in the top), can anyone recommend any short-term fixes while I wait?

[image: Broken Bushings]

Response to comments:

I have a new part coming next week, so I'd like something that will hold up for about a week without further breaking the computer.

I have all the tools I can imagine I'd need for this job - drills/bits, screwdrivers, various epoxies, adhesives, jb weld, etc.

I'm great with tools in other realms although my experience with computer hardware is limited to following along youtube videos.

Two ideas I had are to take all the tension off the spring on that side (Is that possible? foolish?), and drill through where the bushings were, using them as nuts on longer screws and just keep the computer open until I can fix it. I'm not super excited about that options since I have a three-year-old who gets very concerned when things are not as they are supposed to be :)

Comment: Photos would be great. Your description is kind of confusing :)

Comment: Also, describe your level of skill and access to tools and materials.  The kind of fix you could implement could be very different if you're an experienced tech with a machine shop vs. a non-technical user with access to only a screwdriver.

Comment: I had the same problem with my laptop as well. I was unable to "fix it", as the only thing these bushings are mounted to is the plastic of the case. there were no other parts strong enough, and glue certainly won't hold against these forces (if you tried moving that hinge, you know what i mean). I ended up just pressing the display and top case "downwards" (as in, against the bottom part of the case and against the table) when opening and closing it. this largely prevented the hinges from breaking out even more. other than that, i try not to move it too much. sorry that this is no solution :/

Comment: There is epoxy putty that you can mold like clay.  You might be able to build up enough material to hold the bushings temporarily (but be careful not to bond any close-by components).  If there is nothing underneath those holes, and nothing important on the outside of the case, drill the hole completely through the case, use a longer screw, and secure each screw with a washer, lock washer, and nut on the outside of the case (don't tighten excessively).  (cont'd)

Comment: You could also try drilling guide holes deeper, but not completely through the case, and then use longer plastic-tapping screws.  Use epoxy putty to build up and reinforce the plastic around the screws.  Plastic-tapping screws won't provide much strength, though.

Comment: I had been thinking along those lines, but the board for the power switch is under where the hinge rests - if I just drill through I'm concerned the hinge would then be pressing against the circuit board - would an epoxy putty have the compressive strength to protect the circuit board, or would I be looking at some kind of metal sleeve?

Comment: It looks like there are some deep pockets around the posts that held the bushings.  If you can fill some of those cavities with solid blocks of epoxy putty, that should have some compressive strength.  If you can hold the bushings in place, that may be stronger than screwing into the plastic, but you will need a lot of epoxy putty around the bushings to keep them from breaking out like they did on the original.  It will be only as strong as the weakest spot.  Maybe use bushings where you can surround them with a lot of epoxy; screw into plastic where you can't.

Comment: Nate, hopefully this problem has been overtaken by events.  The site is built around a model of questions that have definitive, factual answers.  Your question isn't a good fit because there really isn't a right answer, and it isn't directly applicable to anyone else.  It'd be great if you got some useful input, but the question has made its way to the review queue for closure, and that's the appropriate action at this point.